# Godot 2D Shooting Bullets Upward

Tags: godot

So the code im using for my bullets in my game currently shoot toward the players position. I wanted to know if I could alter it to make them instead shoot straight up. I tried myself a few times, mainly by messing with look_vec, which affects the direction the bullets are fired. But I can only get them to shoot toward the void in some random direction. Can someone help me out?

```
extends Area2D


var move = Vector2.ZERO
var look_vec = Vector2.ZERO
var player = null
var speed = 3
var duration = 5


func _ready():
    connect("body_entered", self, "_on_body_entered")
    
    look_vec = player.position - global_position
    
func _physics_process(delta):
    move = Vector2.ZERO
    
    move = move.move_toward(look_vec, delta)
    move = move.normalized() * speed
    position += move


    duration -= delta
    if duration <= 0 :
        queue_free()

func _on_body_entered(body):
    if body.is_in_group("Player"):
        body.damaged(25)
        queue_free()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us start where you set `look_vec`… This line is already odd:

```
look_vec = player.position - global_position
```

For starters, these are two different vector spaces. It could be that the local space of the player and the global space happen to match. Anyway, if you wanted to take the difference in global space, it would be like this:

```
look_vec = player.global_position - global_position
```

The geometric interpretation is that `look_vec` is a vector that goes from the position of the `Area2D` to the position of the player. *Which makes sense since you say your code shoots towards the player.*

---

If that was odd, this is weird:

```
    move = Vector2.ZERO
    
    move = move.move_toward(look_vec, delta)
    move = move.normalized() * speed
    position += move
```

So you take the zero vector and move it in the direction of `look_vec` some distance given by `delta` (which is time, not distance). But that distance does not matter because you normalize the vector right away. Thus, this is equivalent:

```
    move = look_vec.normalized() * speed
    position += move
```

And that is wrong. Here `move` is a velocity, not a displacement. You need to use `delta`. This is how it should look like:

```
    move = look_vec.normalized() * speed * delta
    position += move
```

Remember that `speed` is distance divided by time. So when we multiply `speed` by the `delta` time, you are left with distance. By adding `move` to `position` you are displacing `position` that distance. *I hope that makes sense.*

---

Now notice that you never change `look_vec`. Thus, instead of normalizing it every time here:

```
    move = look_vec.normalized() * speed * delta
    position += move
```

You can do that once where you set it:

```
look_vec = (player.global_position - global_position).normalized()
```

Leaving the `move` code like this:

```
    move = look_vec * speed * delta
    position += move
```

In fact, there is a short hand method for that:

```
look_vec = global_position.direction_to(player.global_position)
```

And yes, that means that `look_vec` is now a direction. Perhaps rename it accordingly:

```
direction = global_position.direction_to(player.global_position)
```

And

```
    move = direction * speed * delta
    position += move
```

---

*You might go an step further and pre-compute `look_vec * speed`. You can call the variable `velocity`, because a speed with a direction is a velocity*

```
direction = global_position.direction_to(player.global_position)
velocity = direction * speed
```

And

```
    position += velocity * delta
```

---

Finally, you want to change the direction to be straight up? Change the direction to be straight up!

```
direction = Vector2.UP
```